# How to send data between windows and android without being on the same network and without internet?

Tags: android, windows, networking, wireless, transfer

I'm looking for a (usable and reliable) way to send data from an Android device to a Windows PC. I'm trying to build an app similar to AirDroid, that can transfer files wirelessly between devices and also mirror notifications. I managed to do this via a LAN connection, but I would like to do it without using any network.

It would be best if it would not require the user to do much work.

Any suggestions ?

PS: The devices will be in the same room

Comment: The distance is a hundred miles? Or more?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, I'm very sorry. The devices should be in the same room or something similar.

Comment: Well... please tell... which techniques come to mind?

Comment: Well, obviously bluetooth could work. But maybe there's something better (I hope so).

Comment: Checkout this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Comment: @InziKhan does that also work on windows ?

Comment: @SebastianGrigor Not with all windows but those which support wifi direct.

Comment: @InziKhan Then I think that's what I was looking for. I'll look into it. Thank you.

Comment: @SebastianGrigor Sure,Just dont try to reinvent the wheel, there should be some libraries that can do these things ,So just give them a try.Happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do the transfer without being in the same connection and without using LAN (or any cable for that matter). I could only think of using Bluetooth.

If your app (at both the mobile and PC side) has Bluetooth permission, you can easily achieve the transfer without much user interaction.
However, this only works for short distances (obviously).

If you're looking for long distance communication, internet is your best bet.

Comment: I might use bluetooth it I don't find a better alternative. Thank you.